# How could this basic HTML be externalized from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

*Currently have the following Node.js architecture: index.js + server.js + router.js + requestHandlers.js*

HTML is currently embedded in requestHandlers.js, effectively making Node.js the View & Controller.

**What is an easy way for the HTML be externalized?**

requestHandlers.js:

```
var querystring = require("querystring"),
    fs = require("fs");

function start(response, postData) {
    console.log("Request handler 'start' was called.");

    var body = '<html>'+
        '<head>'+
        '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" '+
        'content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'+
        '</head>'+
        '<body>'+
        '<form action="/upload" method="post">'+
        '<textarea name="text" rows="20" cols="60"></textarea>'+
        '<input type="submit" value="Submit text" />'+
        '</form>'+
        '</body>'+
        '</html>';

        response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});
        response.write(body);
        response.end();
}

function upload(response, postData) {
    console.log("Request handler 'upload' was called.");
    response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
    response.write("You've sent the text: "+
    querystring.parse(postData).text);
    response.end();
}

exports.start = start;
exports.upload = upload;
exports.show = show;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd reccommend you not to re-invent the wheel and use some framework, like express.

But if you want to do it your way, then you should use some templating engine, like dust / mustache /jade and put all your html into separate template files.

Then, when you handle your request, you use file input/output , to read those files, pass them through template engine, and send the result to client.

you could do something like this

```
fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('./views/index.html', 'utf8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  //data now contains the content of index.html, do what you want with it
});
```

Comment: would be great to use express.js.. am new to javascript application programming though.. found this: http://howtonode.org/express-mongodb, but it's apparently outdated.. any suggestions for a next step?

Comment: Express is not outdated, mongo is not out dated and mongoose is not outdated. If you meant that the tutorial is outdated, then, you can always use the software's homepage and their installation instructions.
I just finished setting up express---mongo---mongoose---dust and it was quite easy.

Comment: the tutorial is outdated.. understanding it conceptually, a workable implementation is the current milestone.. just looking to get the parts to talk and iterate from there.. do you know of a good tutorial?